# Jobs main page is down? While other pages work fine

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

StackOverflow Jobs seems to be partially down. At least, main page is not working for me.

I'd like to query some specific jobs, but it won't let me to the main page of Jobs.
However, if I open a job form ad/by link it works just fine.

Comment: No repro: https://stackoverflow.com/jobs works fine for me. What exactly do you mean by "not working"? What browser are you using?

Comment: It's not working for me as well. I'm getting "Oops! Something Bad Happened!" page. I'm on Chrome.
https://stackoverflow.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/so-proxy/jobs

Comment: Well, it's working now..

Answer (score 4):

Thank you for reporting this.  We did experience a brief outage on the `/jobs` page for some users and it has resolved.